# Killing process of a user before deleting

Tags: bash

I'm trying to put an if else statement in my script that if deleting of a user is going on, it should automatically check if any process is running by any user and it should be able to kill all those and then delete user.

```
if ps -u $name
then
    sudo pkill -u $name
   sudo userdel $name -r -f      
    echo "The user - $name - has been deleted!"
done < "$fname"                         # double-quote fname
else
   sudo userdel $name -r -f      
    echo "The user - $name - has been deleted!"
done < "$fname"                         # double-quote fname
fi
```

I know I'm failing to put the ps command in action, I know how to list user processes and kill them all, but failing to automatically put that into script to check if processes running, then do this else do this.. 'if processes running by user' is my problem.

Comment: Why do you have `done` in the script, there is no `loop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man ps` mentions the `U` flag to  `ps` to filter by effective user ID. `-o` defines the output, so you can just get the process IDs. Since `ps` also prints "PID" as column header, you need to discard the first line of the `ps` output.

```
for pid in `ps U "$name" -o pid | head -n -1` 
do
    sudo kill -KILL $pid
done
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I would take off the `if` statement. It's redundant due to `for` will already do nothing if `$pids` is empty.

Comment: I tried putting this in my script, but it says `pids` command not found :/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping, you can read all running `PID`s for user `$name` into an array. Test if there is anything in the array, then if so, kill all procs without looping. It's just another approach to the problem. Example:

```
!#/bin/bash

uprocs=( $(pgrep -u $name ) )       # fill array with PIDs owned by $name

[ "${#uprocs[@]}" -gt 0 ] &&        # if procs exist, kill them all
sudo kill "${uprocs[@]}"    
sudo userdel $name -r -f            # delete the user
unset uprocs                        # unset array
```

If you wanted to use a loop, you could then also do:

```
for i in ${uprocs[@]}; do
    sudo kill $i
done
```

Also, you should move away from placing `sudo` inside scripts (there are times it is correct), but generally, if you are administering the system with a script, you should run the script as root. Either by:

```
sudo ./scriptname.sh
```

or by using the `super user` command:

```
su -c ./scriptname.sh
```

That way the script is run with `UID=0` and you don't have to precede all commands by `sudo` within the script. There are advantages/disadvantages either way, but generally you want to avoid filling scripts with `sudo foo`.